# simple for loop // but strange output answer

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, flashdevelop

I'm trying to understand why the output for z is always -1 whenever I trace the variable. I'm counting coins and I'm trying to set up a for loop, however, I'm always prompted by an error because of z = -1.

```
for (var z:int = coins.length; z >= 0; z--);
{
   trace(z);
   trace(coins.length);
}
```

The output answer I get for these two variables are:

```
Z = -1
coins.length = 3
```

Why is this the case? Because all I'm seeing on the output box is:

```
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
keeps repeating
```

If we were to go by the for loop logic, shouldn't the variable z be like this instead?

```
2
1
0
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: edit: Now after debugging it code after code, it says the variable z is undefined. Why is it undefined when I declared z as coins.length that has a value of 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's your problem:

```
for (var z:int = coins.length; z >= 0; z--); // the semicolon at the end.
```

With the semicolon, the loop ends. You wrote a loop without a body. That's perfectly valid and executes just fine.

**After** the loop, the following code is executed once:

```
{
   trace(z);
   trace(coins.length);
}
```

`z` is -1, because that's its last value in the loop which causes the loop to stop executing. `coins.length` never changed and has a value according to the array.

> If we were to go by the for loop logic, shouldn't the variable z be like this instead?

```
2
1
0
```

No, because it starts at 3, not 2.

Comment: Good catch @null.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH my god! Thank you so much! I am super embarrassed haha. I'll have to really double check next time.